# Can't Center Horizontal Navigation in WordPress Theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I am working on http://pizzli.com/toothworks. I am trying to center my vertical navigation, so that it is centered in the head image on all browsers, however when I zoom out, it seems to move. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Inline-Block didn't seem to work. I need to keep it as relative due to the Jquery dropdown

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ul.topnav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 900px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 230px;
}

#header {
background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat center center;
width: 1260px;
height: 55px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That sort of worked. I need the header to stretch across the page though.

Comment: then I would implement the solution I just offered, then get a piece of that header image to repeat-x across the top in a div with width:100%

Comment: The site is really messed up in IE, any suggestions?

Comment: its not that messed up. make the bigger part of the header (that holds the links) larger, and then either set the background to #BCF0F6, or make the background an actual img tag with a width of 100%